# Redirection after login to reset password in Symfony

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I'm trying to redirect the user to force them to change/reset their password when it is their first login and when they have the property "IsPasswordChange" false but the issue is that I have a too many redirects error. If someone can help me find the problem, thank you.

LoginEvent.php :

```
    class LoginEvent implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private Security $security;
    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(Security $security, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [
                ['forcePasswordChange', 0]
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function forcePasswordChange(RequestEvent $event): void
    {

        // only deal with the main request, disregard subrequests
        if (!$event->isMainRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        // if we are visiting the password change route, no need to redirect
        if ($event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route') == 'app_reset_password') {
            return;
        }

        $user = $this->security->getUser();
        // if you do not have a valid user, it means it's not an authenticated request, so it's not our concern
        if (!$user instanceof Partenaire) {
            return;
        }

        // if it's not their first login, and have is password changed = true, no need to redirect
        if ($user->isIsPasswordChange()) {
            return;
        }

        // if we get here, it means we need to redirect them to the password change view.
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_reset_password', [
            'token' => $user->getUserIdentifier()
        ])));



    }


}
```

security.yaml :

```
    security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [ app_admin_provider, app_partenaire_provider, app_structure_provider ]

        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_admin_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Admin
                property: email

        app_partenaire_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Partenaire
                property: email

        app_structure_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Structure
                property: email
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: chain_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:

         - { path: ^/homepage, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_PARTENAIRE] },
         - { path: ^/homepage-admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN },



    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_PARTENAIRE, ROLE_STRUCTURE ]

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

Comment: We may need to look at your `security.yaml`

Comment: The code seems right to me unless you have something else funky going on.  The chain provider is a bit unusual but really should not impact anything.  I suppose you could replace the chain provider with just app_partenaire_provider in your firewall just to verify.  Having your tried some dump and die statements right before your redirect?

Comment: Yes so I tried with the providers , nothing changed. I tried to do some dump and everything seems alright to me

Comment: You might try accessing the reset password url by typing it into your browser.  And comment out the access control line in security.yaml just for testing.  Maybe the url is getting blocked somewhere.

Comment: Ok I find the problem, there was an issue in the controller of the reset password

Answer (score 0):

I think you are entering in an infinite loop because you are listening to the request event then you perform an action that ends up with another request so the loop restarts.

Maybe you can listen the LoginSuccessEvent